# GoogleDrive zip corrupt

Tags: zip, drive, corrupt

I zipped some files, intrinsically important (old code, tune ideas, a few recording sessions). Put them on Google Drive. All the zips are corrupt. I just wanted to hear a tune from yesteryear now I realize it might all be gone.

I've tried 
zip -F x.zip --out y.zip

no dice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use 7-zip to unpack the file. I read it somewhere else and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a shot in the dark but maybe try using Google's official client to get the file rather than downloading through the browser (if that's what you did before).

https://www.google.com/drive/download/

Answer (score 0):

I just used 7-zip as suggested above.  It worked, but there was an error message for one of the files.  It turned out that the filename was invalid for windows -- it had an embedded slash.  The zip file was usable, and included all of the other files.  Once I fixed the file name on the google drive folder, the download worked correctly.

So it makes sense that there would be problems with a zip file that include a file with an invalid name.  But it would have been good if Windows could have supplied a bit more information about the problem.